# Why does the using of dict make MapReduce slowly?

Tags: python, hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, bigdata

There is a problem that I have some logs, each line of the log contains of `question_id, user_id, content and timestamp`, it's just like some forum data.

What I need to do is **using MapReduce to calculate the top 10 popular questions**.

I wrote mapper to output `<question_id, 1>` pairs for each line of the log and reducer calculate the total amount of `user_id` for each `question_id`.

Then I found that there are too many output made by the mapper. This may **cost lots of time to shuffle and sort the data from disk and network**. So I did an optimization that I used dict(or map) to store the amount of `user_id` for each question, for example, `<qid1, uid1> <qid1, uid2>` can be optimized to `<qid1, 2>` and 2 is the amount of `user_id` for `qid1`.

But, sadly, this solution is slower than the first algorithm. I think the access of dict(map) may increase the time consuming.

**The environment**:

- Cloudra Virtual Machine
- 2 cores, 2GB memory

**Questions**:

- Are the data size and the number of hosts the key for choosing an algorithm?
- how to determine which one is better for me? (I have to try the two algorithms, and find which one is better?)

Comment: Why do you need user_id in the first place? Surely your map step could simply project the question_id, and reduce the amount of data you need to store in memory?

Comment: sorry, I have edited it. but It's not the key.

Comment: Have you considered using a Combiner to basically do the dictionary part for you?